# Istio - How to differentiate between normal call and retried call?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I have ISTIO Access logging enabled.
If a service A calls service B, and if Service B returns say 5xx, then istio from service A will retry the call.

This will result in 2 access logs, one for the first call and one for the retried call.

How can I identify which call is the first and which is the retried call? They don't seem to have the same requestId.